# Set mod_reqtimeout to unlimited time for a specific folder

Tags: apache, apache2

I basically have two questions:
How do you set the RequestReadTimeout (in mod_reqtimeout), header and body time to: unlimited time

and
How do I apply that to a specific folder?

The default reqtimeout.conf is:

```
<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
  RequestReadTimeout header=10-20,minrate=500
  RequestReadTimeout body=10,minrate=500
</IfModule>
```

So that it would be something like:

```
<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
  #Apply this to the /var/www/unlimitedtime folder
  <Directory /var/www/unlimitedtime>
    RequestReadTimeout header=unlimited,MinRate=0 body=unlimited,MinRate=0
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

This doesn't work but it's just an example that maybe will make my question more clear.

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several tips from [official documentation of top
RequestReadTimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html#requestreadtimeout) :

> Context:  server config, virtual host

That means this directive is a quite high level directive, you do not have the `Location` or `Directory` context here. In fact the timeouts are applied far before the web server can apply a directory decision on the request (the request is not received...), so it's quite normal. What it means is that you **cannot apply this directive in a Directory**, and there's nothing you can do for that, sorry.

> type=timeout
>
> The time in seconds allowed for reading all of the request headers or
>   body, respectively. **A value of 0 means no limit**.

So instead of using the `10-20` form simply set `0` and it becomes an unlimited timeout. Or at least that's what the documentation seems to imply. But that's a real nice way of making your webserver DOS-enabled. A few HTTP requests on the right url and you will get a nice **Deny of Service**, so I hope some other Timeout setting will override it (but maybe not, be careful) :-)